# Antenna preamplifier

Tags: transistors, antenna, sdr

I'm designing an antenna preamplifier for my SDR Receiver. I checked some designs online but I decided to set for simple transistors as I have no source for JFETs and battery powered to make it portable. What I came up is below:
[image: preampli]

I checked the circuit on the oscilloscope and should give around 100 or more gain. Sadly with or without preamplifier I don't see any difference in the signal strength, also changing the antenna as a dipole or a long wire antenna. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** futher info: sorry I didn't specify it in the question but I used the 2N2222 just as a test because is what I had on hand. Optimally the frequencies that I'm interested in are the HF spectrum.

Comment: What frequencies? What antenna? a short piece of wire , or a quarterwave whip, or dipole run thru a balun to convert from balanced to single-ended-50-ohm? What noise floor?

Comment: A broadband, lightly biased preamp like this invites intermodulation distortion. Its gain at high radio frequencies will be far below 100.

Comment: Get to grips with a sim like LTSpice. It's free and will be the best investment in your own time you'll ever make if you are interested in designing. Single resistor biasing is a problem - don't do it and don't expect to see much in the way of output signal with a common emitter configuration loaded with 50 ohms. Ditto what the above say.

Comment: You left off all-important information like what frequency range and what antenna impedance.  Also, any amplifier will reduce signal to noise ratio.  How do you know that amplifying the signal will help?  Your radio probably already has a LNA after the antenna.  The issue may be one of signal to noise, not of absolute signal strength.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf So far I have tried a 4m wire and a about 60 cm dipole with a 4:1 balun

Comment: @Andyaka I'm using QUCS for simulations and that's what I used to get the values for the circuit

Comment: @OlinLathrop in all reality, I assumed an amplifier would help. How do I up the signal to noise ratio?

Comment: @Luca you can't with an amplifier *improve* SNR. That's physically impossible. Filtering can remove noise power. So, use a low-insertion loss filter in front of a low-noise amplifier.

Comment: Well, with a different transistor, you'd also not use the same amplifier topology, I guess. So, what's left of your question then, other than "if I redid my amplifier design, what should I do?"?

Comment: Since you refuse to answer questions, have a -1 to go along with the *unclear* vote from earlier.

Comment: @OlinLathrop he added info to the question: – HF band; in a comment he mentioned a 60cm dipole. None of this makes sense; I'm agreeing with the -1 and close vote, although I definitely sunk time into this.

Comment: @Marcus: He added something to the question, but all he has said about the frequency, despite direct questions, is "HF spectrum".  I assume "HF" means "high frequency", so that's totally useless.

Comment: I think he's referring to the "classical" definition of HF, being 3–30 MHz. That would align with his previous question. But even there he was, from multiple sides, recommended to use modern semiconductors and amplifier designs rather than leftovers from 1960s/70s ham magazines.

Comment: @Luca just so you get a feeling for what to look for in an RF transistor datasheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/408/DST_2SC5086-TDE_EN_5027-736632.pdf and what an LNA datasheet looks like: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/472/SKY65452_92LF_203095D-876378.pdf You'll notice that using a proper LNA IC makes your life a lot easier, and your reception actually better. You'll of course have to match 75Ω to whatever antenna you're using, and to whatever receiver you're using, but matching circuits for <30 MHz are relatively easy to build well, I guess.

Comment: @OlinLathrop since we are speaking of radios I assumed that HF spectrum was info enough for the range 2-20 MHz (about). So much so that Marcus understood
I'm sorry that this question spurred so much unrest. It's just so that whatever you search online redirects to 70s designs, it's not my fault, I don't know where to search. But I suppose this is probably not a good place for a beginner to start asking questions, although I tought so. I suppose I shall put a huge label at the beginning of my future questions "I'm a biologist, not an engineer".

Comment: Besides, @MarcusMüller made the point, that I didn't think of, that an amplifier doesn't indeed improve the signal to noise ratio. I wanted to ask further to that but I don't want to spur further chaos. Should I ask another question or should I change this one to better reflect my new question (rendering the answers pointless)? I mean, at this point the current question doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @Luca if you're saying "HF" as in "the band called HF", it's definitely 3–30 MHz, not 2–20 :) You're very welcome to ask questions! But what you're doing is setting up a complex design, and then ask for feedback on what might be not optimal with it. That of course raises the reaction that the best way to improve that design is to remove the complexity, and look at the market for RF components, and then build a simpler design around a suitable amplifier :) that's basically all I want to encourage!

Comment: @Luca notice that you might still need an amplifier, whether it improves SNR or not, if your SDR's ADC is not being used within (nearly) it's full scale – in that case, you'd be wasting signal quality on large quantization steps. So, the question "how to improve my receiver's reception" is a very valid one – but it would probably fit better on ham.stackexchange.com AND it will require that you're more describing the wholeness of your system, rather than just picking an amplifier design (which is but a small building block of the whole), and then ask for where exactly you can help your system!

Comment: @MarcusMüller if you ask me, the reaction I got is mostly downvotes for no apparent reason, even after clarification and that is terribly frustrating, especially for somebody that is starting and doesn't know where to bang his head.
I don't want to criticize anybody but get into the shoes of somebody that just started: if I want to start from somewhere I google it and get only designs from the 70s, if I ask how to improve a specific design, than i get that I should look for better parts and when I ask for which parts for a job I don't get any answer because it's pointless to ask for parts.

Comment: But I don't want to stray this from the topic so be it, I will ask elsewhere and search elsewhere. Just my two cents guys (all of you, nothing particular), realize how much somebody like me is "welcome to ask questions" if anything you get is downvoting. Now you can close the question for all I care.

Comment: Well,I can understand that it's frustrating;I'm coming from the other side:put yourself in t. shoes of someone who actually wants to help someone to build a practical system,but they just come up with a obsolete design and hope to improve that beyond technical sensibility.To make an analogy:assume you're an expert on professional cleaning of clothes,and there's someone who's coming insisting on you telling him how to improve his clotheswasher based on the wash board design he found in an ancient book–would you be able to honestly help him improve his wash board, or recommend a washing machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62773/discussion-between-luca-and-marcus-muller).

Answer (score 2):

The Q2n2222 is a 2N2222 clone.

It's ancient. It was  marketed as a *switching* transistor, the datasheets you can still find for this type of transistor usually don't even specify frequency-dependent behaviour, base-emitter capacity is only spec'ed below 1 MHz, the cutoff currents are relatively high… this is amongs the least suitable transistors you could find for an RF antenna amplifier.

The noise figure of a two-stage amplifier of that is probably way worse than what your SDR has.

It's a bit hard to guess, but I'd expect this to have a relatively terrible linearity, making this a really bad choice for a broadband receiver.

Hence, using this preamplifier is counter-productive, as you'll drown weak signals in more noise and intermodulation.

Instead, buy an LNA chip designed for the frequency band of interest. You don't say which frequencies this is for, so it's hard to recommend anything specifically, but I'm sure you'll find appropriate low-noise amplifiers on the websites of TI, ST, NXP, Analog Devices and/or Maxim Integrated, amongst a lot of others.

We've discussed this before, but JFETs aren't new technology - in fact, in many places, like this one, they've mostly become nearly as obsolete as the circuits used before their rise, like the one you display here. Wherever you're taking your circuits from is hopelessly stuck in the past, and that's bad, performance-wise.

So, if you want to improve the reception of a device made of 2010's semiconductors, it's really not appropriate to stick to the cheapest semiconductors that the 1970s have left on the market.

Instead of digging up obsolete amplifier designs, go for a modern IC, and the reference circuits you'll find in its datasheet or in the further documentation the manufacturers provide.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't specify it in the question but I used the 2N2222 just as a test because is what I had on hand.
Optimally the frequencies that I'm interested in are the HF spectrum. I will search further for parts then

Comment: ... as said, search for LNAs. They come in easy-to-use packages, and with reference designs of their manufacturers that are tested. For HF, you can also use high-bandwidth Opamps (I think I mentioned that before elsewhere).

Comment: Add the info that you're giving in your comment here to your question, or someone might close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here's an excellent preamp design**](http://www.w0btu.com/W0BTU-broadband-preamps.html).

### It will FAR outperform many of the designs listed here.

It uses a single NPN bipolar transistor, and works from about 100 khz to about 30 MHz. A 2N5109 or an MRF5812 work well

It's based on a design in *Solid State Design For the Radio Amateur*, © 1977 ARRL - Pages 97, 98, 122, 123. I have been using this preamp here for many decades.

Performance specs per W7IUV:

> P1dB (1 dB output compression power) should be greater than +21 dBm.
>   Usually runs about +24 to +27 depending on parts used.
>
> OIP3 (output third order intercept point) should be +41 dBm or
>   greater. I’ve seen +44, which is as high as I can accurately measure
>   with my test setup.

Somewhere, I thought he *implied* that the noise figure is about 6 dB. I don't know what it is. Whatever it is, *the NF is lower without his emitter resistor mod*.

[image: W0BTU preamp]

[image: Preamp schematic]

Comment: how is a NF of 6dB considered "FAR" outperforming e.g a low-noise adjustable active filter opamp configuration? What about actual LNA ICs that come with NFs < 2dB for these frequency ranges?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry, I didn't mean your design. However -assuming that it is 6 dB- is usually plenty good enough for HF, since the noise floor is normally higher than that. *And I'm not at all sure about the NF.*

Comment: Fair enough! Point is that a lot of what makes your design a *good* design is that it uses an –at that time– good transistor (you can definitely buy better these days) and well-defined bandwidth, as well as only one gain stage (which limits the noise). I think that might not be what OP is after, seeing that he's connecting an SDR receiver.

Comment: This preamp was designed by no less an RF electronics expert than Wes Stewart N7WS himself, one of the few amateur stations in the world where all the radio gear was designed and built by the operator. This design has even been used by many well-known contesters and high-profile super stations for several decades. However, I've lost several transistors from static and lightning before I added the back-to-back protection diodes on the input. The 2K pot on the input can also be used to reduce the level if any IMD is noticed, usually without any decreased ability in hearing weak stations.

Answer (score 0):

{added the ARRL/ham preamp at end; comments are welcome}
Try this; bandwidth will be LOW (Q1 collector tau is 2.2Kohm and 20+pf, or 50 nanoseconds, or 3MHz); the 20+pf is 2 * C_ob of the NPNs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feS0fJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And now that ARRL LNA schematic, redrawn so I might understand it. Anyone have comments on this, particularly the "transformer"?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd5510.png)</sup>